# Vim fails to save the commit message

Tags: git, macos, github, vim, git-commit

I am facing issues while updating my fork.

I get this error when I do `git merge upstream/master`

Vim editor opens - I enter my commit message but on saving and exiting it  fails to save the message.

> Removing xyz/abc/is_dates.py
>   vim-gitgutter: requires Vim 7.3.105
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue
>   error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
>   Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

Comment: your vim version seems to be causing the issue. have you tried sudo apt-get install --upgrade vim? Alternatively, you could try disabling vim-gitgutter and see if that helps.

Comment: For me it says, `Error: vim 8.0.1650_1 already installed` when I do `brew upgrade vim`

Comment: you seem to have some plugin which is incompatible with installed vim version

Comment: does your vim work otherwise? Maybe git runs something else than your regular one

Comment: Meanwhile, you can bypass it with `git commit -m "this is my commit message"`

Comment: @max630 The problems started after installing `git-gutter`

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this seemed to allow me to atleast save my message.
`git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim`

But I can't get rid of the error 
`vim-gitgutter: requires Vim 7.3.105 Press ENTER or type command to continue`

It does not let me update it either.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins require certain Vim features to run, and perform a version check during startup. You seem to be using an older, unsupported Vim version with the *gitgutter* plugin.

- If this plugin works in other (non-Git) Vim sessions, it may be the case that Git is using a different (outdated) Vim installation. You can check with Vim is running via `:echo v:progpath`. Align your Git config to use the current Vim version, or update the outdated one.
- If you just have a single Vim installation, update it (Vim 7.3 is from 2010 and *very* outdated. It should be possible to install the latest version 8.1; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from the [Cream project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/)), it's also not very difficult to [compile](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (e.g. from the GitHub sources) on Linux.) If you can't, you need to remove the plugin to get rid of the message.